# How to display file names BEFORE submit in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I want to see the names of each file I uploaded to the form **before** clicking the submit button and with the option to remove it if I want, how do I do this in laravel?
i'm using laravel 8

View:

```
<div class="mb-3">
   <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label" >Receita</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFileMultiple" name="files[]" multiple>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
 foreach ($request->file('files') as  $files) {
            Document::create([
                'COD_TIPO_DOCUMENTO'    => 1,
                'NOME_DOCUMENTO'        => $files->getClientOriginalName(),
                'DS_CAMINHO_DOCUMENTO'  => $files->store('orders'),
                'DT_CADASTRO'           => Carbon::now(),
                'NOME_EXTENSAO'         => $files->getClientOriginalExtension(),
                'DS_MIME_TYPE'          => $files->getClientMimeType()
            ]);
        }
```

Prototype:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggxSi.png

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. Have you done any research?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to use [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) or [uppy](https://uppy.io/) for uploading files

Comment: @ADyson I see some solutions with js and jquery, but i create the question to know if i can use only php to make this

Comment: No you can't, because _before_ the file is uploaded, PHP has not been activated because no request has been sent to the server. PHP cannot be activated until the upload is sent. That is quite simple to work out if you understand the key concepts of how web applications work. If you haven't sent something to the server then the server side code cannot do anything with it.